# Issue using Twitter REST API

Tags: java, twitter

I have a list of screen names on Twitter and I wish to get meta data about their twitter profile. I am using Twitter's [REST API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-API-Documentation) for the same. The  [users/show](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-users%C2%A0show)  method is apt for my task. The API documentation clearly states that it requires no authentication. Here's the code I wrote for my task:

```
package Twitter;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class TwitterAPI {

    private static String url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/";

    /*
     * Sends a HTTP GET request to a URL     
     * @return - The response from the end point
     */
    public static String sendGetRequest(String endpoint, String screen_name) {
        String result = null;


        if (endpoint.startsWith("http://")){
            //Send HTTP request to the servlet
            try {
                //Construct data
                StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();

                //Send data
                String urlStr = endpoint ;  

                if(screen_name!=null && screen_name.length() > 0){
                    urlStr += screen_name + ".json";
                }
                System.out.println(screen_name.length());
                System.out.println("The URL call is: " + urlStr);
                URL url = new URL(urlStr);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection ();

                //Get the response
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                String line;

                while((line = rd.readLine())!=null){
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                rd.close();
                result = sb.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                //If API issue, collect screen names to write to API issue file             
                System.out.println("Twitter API issue :" + screen_name);

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        return result;
    }
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String result = sendGetRequest(url, "denzil_correa");
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

However, on running the same I receive the following exception :

```
13
The URL call is: http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/denzil_correa.json
Twitter API issue :denzil_correa
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:365)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:227)
null
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:214)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:531)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:481)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:157)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:233)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:783)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:724)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:649)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:972)
    at Twitter.TwitterAPI.sendGetRequest(TwitterAPI.java:43)
    at Twitter.TwitterAPI.main(TwitterAPI.java:76)
```

The URL is correct as when I try the URL : http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/denzil_correa.json in my browser I receive the following:

```
{"time_zone":"Mumbai","description":"","lang":"en","profile_link_color":"1F98C7","status":{"coordinates":null,"contributors":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":"shailaja","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_user_id":14089830,"in_reply_to_status_id":16789217674,"source":"web","created_at":"Tue Jun 22 19:43:46 +0000 2010","place":null,"geo":null,"favorited":false,"id":16793898396,"text":"@shailaja Harsh !"},"profile_background_image_url":"http://s.twimg.com/a/1276711174/images/themes/theme2/bg.gif","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DAECF4","following":false,"profile_background_tile":false,"created_at":"Sun Jun 29 20:23:29 +0000 2008","statuses_count":1157,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"C6E2EE","profile_use_background_image":true,"followers_count":169,"contributors_enabled":false,"notifications":false,"friends_count":246,"protected":false,"url":"http://https://sites.google.com/a/iiitd.ac.in/denzilc/","profile_image_url":"http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/643636081/Cofee_Mug_normal.jpg","geo_enabled":true,"profile_background_color":"C6E2EE","name":"Denzil Correa","favourites_count":3,"location":"India","screen_name":"denzil_correa","id":15273105,"verified":false,"utc_offset":19800,"profile_text_color":"663B12"}
```

which is in the JSON format I want.

Kindly let me know if I am doing anything stupid here.

Regards,
--Denzil

---

Hank/Splix as told I tried using the  [HTTP Components Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client). Here's my modified code :

```
 
package Twitter;
```

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class TwitterAPI {

```
private static String url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/denzil_correa.json";


/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Here's the error I receive:

```
 
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://api.twitter.com refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:147)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554)
    at Twitter.TwitterAPI.main(TwitterAPI.java:30)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:365)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:227)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:214)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:378)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:531)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
    ... 7 more
```

Surprisingly this also gives a similar exception to the code written for handling HTTP responses manually. I understand that manually handling HTTP responses may be sub-optimal but currently I am not looking at writing optimal code. I would like to get my task done even if it means to be quick & dirty.

Just to let you know, I can successfully call the [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api)  using the first code I posted. I am receiving the same response I would receive if I paste the URL in my browser.

I will also try using the Twitter4J API once again and check if I can get my task done. Will keep you updated.

---

So, here's the code using Twitter4J :

```
package Twitter;
```

import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.User;

public class TwitterAPI {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Twitter unauthenticatedTwitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    try {
        User user = unauthenticatedTwitter.showUser("denzil_correa");

        System.out.println(user.getLocation());
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Pretty straightforward as expected using the API. However, here's the error I receive:

```
Jun 23, 2010 7:12:10 PM twitter4j.internal.logging.CommonsLoggingLogger info
INFO: Using class twitter4j.internal.logging.CommonsLoggingLoggerFactory as logging factory.
Jun 23, 2010 7:12:11 PM twitter4j.internal.logging.CommonsLoggingLogger info
INFO: Use twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl as HttpClient implementation.
TwitterException{statusCode=-1, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null}
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:316)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:68)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:90)
    at twitter4j.Twitter.showUser(Twitter.java:538)
    at Twitter.TwitterAPI.main(TwitterAPI.java:17)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:365)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:227)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:214)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:531)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:152)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.(c.java:166)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.a(c.java:9)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.getNewHttpClient(d.java:55)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:724)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:20)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:972)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:385)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getResponseCode(b.java:52)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpResponseImpl.(HttpResponseImpl.java:42)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:279)
    ... 4 more
```

Again, I see that the error is essentially the same. So, all options tried! I'm sure there's something I am missing here. It would be great if you could point out the same.

---

Hank, Unfortunately the same doesn't work in Python too :-(

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    urllib.urlopen("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/denzil_correa.json").read()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib.py", line 86, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib.py", line 205, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib.py", line 347, in open_http
    errcode, errmsg, headers = h.getreply()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\httplib.py", line 1060, in getreply
    response = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\httplib.py", line 986, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\httplib.py", line 391, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\httplib.py", line 349, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\socket.py", line 397, in readline
    data = recv(1)
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Comment: Why not using `twitter4j` or, at least, `commons httpclient`?

Comment: @splix You should turn this into an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: Thanks Splix! I never knew there existed a http-components-client. I shall use the same henceforth for HTTP Request/Response handling purposes.I tried using the same but it didn't solve my problem. More description in the edit of my original post.

Comment: Hanx/Splix, Please check my latest edits. I tried Twitter4J too. Hasn't helped resolve the issue. Would be nice if you could point out the problem. Thanks :-)

Comment: maybe you are using an proxy at your browser, aren't? had your tried to open connection to some other site to verify connection?

Comment: Splix, As mentioned in my edit I tried using the Facebook Open Graph API and handled the  HTTP response manually. It's working fine. It's just too frustrating to see such a problem. :-(

Comment: To add, yes there is a proxy. But why would it behave differently on different HTTP request-responses from the same program ?

Answer (score 1):

As @splix mentioned in the comments, doing this using just `java.net` is… suboptimal. I've never yet encountered a situation where [`HttpClient`](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/?pli=1) wasn't a better option. Event better is his suggestion of [`twitter4j`](http://osdir.com/ml/twitter-development-talk@googlegroups.com/2010-05/msg01210.html); unless you're trying to create an alternative, it's almost always better to use an API wrapper like that vs. handling the raw HTTP interactions yourself.

UPDATE:

@Denzil it's odd that you're getting this same error even with `twitter4j` (I can't test the code until I get some free time to grab the lib, etc.) so I begin to suspect a problem on Twitter's end. If you have Python installed, try the following:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlopen("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/denzil_correa.json").read()
```

This worked for me.

UPDATE 2:

This definitely sounds like Twitter is intentionally refusing your requests. Possible reasons could include: your IP is on their blacklist for some reason, proxy voodoo, or things I haven't thought of. To elaborate on the proxy voodoo: I don't know what exactly it's doing to your requests, but it's possible it's adding a header or something that the Twitter API doesn't like. I'd recommend contacting Twitter support (if there is such a thing for API problems) or posting to [the mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/?pli=1).

BTW, here's a [thread from the mailing list](http://osdir.com/ml/twitter-development-talk@googlegroups.com/2010-05/msg01210.html) that mentions ways to see if you're blacklisted.

Comment: Hank/Splix, thanks for the response. My experience with Twitter4J is bad. The API returns erratic results for me viz. it sometime returns a result while sometimes doesn't.

Comment: Hank, Tried the same in Python. Doesn't work ! :-O 
Check my edit for the error.

Comment: Hank, Thanks for the update once again. But if I can get the details by posting it in a browser why would there be a problem when I do it via code?

Comment: As @splix mentioned, there might be a difference between the proxied request from your browser and the proxied request from code. You might try checking the headers on the request from the browser and comparing them to the request from the code.

Comment: Hank, Thanks for your response. What still befuddles me is that I use code itself to access the Facebook API without using any proxy authentication in my code. So, if it isn't required for Facebook API I am made to believe it isn't required while using Twitter too. Ultimately, both requests are simple HTTP requests and need to be handled in the same way. The  inconsistency is what is still mucking up my head.

Comment: @Denzil We're beyond anything I actually know anything about and into the realm of guesses. My *guess* is that Twitter doesn't like something that is happening to the proxied request, or possibly that the request is *not* being proxied outside the browser. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Hank, No issues. Thanks for all the help!